# Record audio output from android device using Android SDK

Tags: android, audio-recording

Is it possible to record sound from android device's sound.

I mean.

Android record their sound itself.

or

Android Self Recording. ???

Answer (score 0):

See `MediaRecorder` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) and `AudioRecord` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html)

I have tried them both. I managed to record mic's input, but it didn't work for recording a VoIP call...

Comment: except VoIP call? Hmmm...

It can record sound from game?

Comment: Not except VoIP. May be other conditions that will also not work. I haven't any idea about your problem, but I will back if I find anything.